# Electric field lines fall within a circle?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

I was going through the method of images using 2 positive point charges placed along a line perpendicular to an infinite grounded conducting plate. I had found the surface charge density induced on the surface by these charges and also know that the electric field lines from either of the charges must fall within a circle (since the field lines diverge radially outward from the positive charge trying to end up in the negative image charge. However, I wish to derive the radius of the circle within which the electric field lines will always fall. How am I supposed to attack the problem?

Answer (score 1):

All of the field lines don’t lie within a circle of any finite radius. Think about the field lines that start out heading almost perpendicularly away from the plate.

Comment: But in an image problem, a negative image charge is present whose field lines can terminate on the negative charge right? There will be a maximum radius then. I was wondering how to find it?

Comment: *There will be a maximum radius then.* That doesn’t follow from the existence of the negative image charge.